# How do you open a large blue runed door in Hidden Ourobon?

Tags: guild-wars-2

So I was exploring [Harathi Hinterlands](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Harathi_Hinterlands) and I came across this massive door in [Hidden Ourobon](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Hidden_Ourobon). Does anyone have any idea what it's for or if it can be opened? There appears to be a chamber behind it.

There was an event to kill [Kol Skullsmasher](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Champion_Kol_Skullsmasher) so I guess it could be to do with that?

[image: Rune blocked door]
[image: Map location]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case of this particular 'door', you can access the other side easily enough by walking through the centaur village 'Modniir Gorge' to the north. You walk down a pathway into a cave and can stand on the other side of the 'door' and look back into Hidden Ourobon. Not sure why they would put a short cut between the village and hidden Ourobon or how you open it but seems more likely to be tied to an event rather than a future portal imho.

Comment: You're right, confirmed myself on Tuesday night :) Odd that it should be blocked off. Perhaps it was open before they put the Champion event in. http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Defeat_Ulgoth_the_Modniir_and_his_minions